# How to send clientIP in request headers using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios, server-side-rendering

My current Project structure is like this

```
- MyApp
  - client
  - config
  - server
  - shared
    - src
        myReactApp.jsx
    - services
        api.js
        userService.js
```

I want to send the client's IP address to the API server in all requests as a header
I am using Axios to make requests to the server
my `api.js` file has this

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default () =>
  axios.create({
    baseURL: config('apiUrl')
  });
```

and in my user service I call api.js like this

```
import api from './api'
export default {
  fetchUserProfileDetails() {
    return api().get('/user/profile')
  }
}
```

which I then use in my components as

```
import UserService from '../userService'

...

componentDidMount () {
  UserService.fetchUserProfileDetails()
  .then(results => {
    // do stuff with the results
  })
}
```

what I want to know is how to send in the client's IP address in every request when I have this kind of setup
The application is react based and is also Server-Side Rendered using `express` as the server
I am able to get the Client's IP using `req.connection.socket.remoteAddress.split(",")[0]` and am also able to send that into the react application.

How to actually use that in axios?

I am using react's context API to send the IP inside the react application, is that a proper way to send information from the server to the react application?

Comment: Send an XFF header https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For

Answer (score 2):

If you can already get the client's IP on your code you can set the default header of Axios just like `axios.defaults.headers.common['CLIENT_IP'] = clientIP`.

If you don't have the client IP you can get that with third party app other with some code. Just take a look on this article https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/257/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-with-javascript-only

But to get it it's better to use your server. In Express it's just `req.ip`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood
I already have the IP, what I dont understand is how to inject it into axios, since the IP is being sent to the react application using context API, which is initialized only once(at the start of the react application)

Comment: Then save it in a global variable like window or LocalStorage or Cookie and update the `axios.defaults.headers.common` property when you make a request. It is this property which contains headers sent.